# Could not sign in Youtube on Apple TV 4

Tags: appletv, youtube

To sign in the YouTube app on my apple TV 4, it ask me to go

youtube.com/active

When I go to that page, the page says

> "This account has been terminated for violating YouTube or Google's Terms of Service."

However, I could use my account on YouTube on other platforms just fine. I contacted Google and filled in a form to check my account status. I got e-mail replay says my account still active. Does anybody faced this 
situation？ What could I do?

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you solve this problem?

Comment: @JFu Yes I did. I reset my Apple tv, updated to newest version, download youtube again and it worked.